Find the cheapest way to make two lists of numbers match in how often each number appears

Given two arrays, A and B, each containing N positive integers, determine the minimum cost to equalize the frequency distribution of elements in both arrays. The cost of swapping an element between the arrays is defined as the lesser of the two values being exchanged. Find the minimum cost required to do so. If not possible, return -1.

Test Case 1:
  Input: 
    [4, 2, 1, 1]
    [4, 2, 2, 2]
  Output: 
    1

Test Case 2:
  Input:
    [1, 10, 10]
    [1, 20, 20]
  Output:
    2

The best choice would be to swap a 1 from the first array and a 2 from the second array which has a cost of 1 after which they become [4, 2, 1, 2], [4, 2, 2, 1] that is required by the question.
If the total count of any number across both arrays is odd, it's impossible to balance the arrays. In this case we return -1.
My approach involved creating two dictionaries to track the frequency of elements in each array. For array A, we have mp_A = {4: 1, 2: 1, 1: 2}, and for array B, mp_B = {4: 1, 2: 3}. Since there are a total of four 2's, we need two in each array, requiring one swap.
I then created an array containing the numbers to be swapped and their swap quantities. In this case, we get arr = [[2, 1], [1, 1]], which is sorted based on the first element of each subarray.
Next, I employed a two-pointer approach with i = 0 and j = length of arr - 1. We continue using the element at arr[i] as long as possible. For example, if the array was [[x, 2], [y, 1], [z, 1]] where x < y < z, we could use one x for z and another for y, resulting in a minimum cost of 2x.


Edited:
The comments below have helped in proving the above technique wrong but I don't know how do I proceed with its implementation or what is the approach to solving this question.

There's no guarantee your swap strategy is optimal. If you need to move a 10 in one direction and a 20 in the other, it may be better to swap the 10 with a 1, then swap the 1 back for the 20, for example.

"But this approach seems to be failing somewhere which I am not able to think of." Then how do you know it is failing?

@ScottHunter, did not pass all the testcases in the exam which were locked.

To make @user2357112's point more concrete: suppose your lists were [1,10,10] and [1,20,20].

@ScottHunter Ah, I get it, swap the 10 in first with 1 in second -> [1, 10, 1], [10, 20, 20]. Swap the 20 in second with 1 in first -> [1, 10, 20], [10, 20, 1], cost=2.

You've already figured out what swaps need to be made; for each, check to see if it can be done cheaper as 2 swaps with the smallest value.
